# How to use include or require_once on If else statement on php?

Tags: php

I have two file `if.php` and `index.php`,  I want to use `if.php` to store the if condition form if statement. But it seems not working. Is it possible to do it? thank you

**if.php**

```
<?php 
if(Three == 3) { 
 //do something
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
 require_once 'if.php';
else{
  //do something
}?>
```

Update:
Beacase I have a lot of index.php(such as index1.php ,index2.php,index3.php.........................index731.php)

If I need to keep update for  if statement.....
First day needto add if(One == 1) , Second day  need to add  if(One == 1, Two== Three)

so If I need to add value in if statement, I need to change a lot of page!!!!!!
but finally ,I find solution.

**if.php**

```
<?php
    if(Three == 3) {
        $session_admin =true; 
    }
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'if.php';
if($session_admin ==true){
//do something
}else{
  //do something
}?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each PHP file is compiled individually and it must be syntactically correct. It is **not possible** to start a [control structure](http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php), [function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php) or [class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) in a file and close it in a different file.

It is, however, possible to [return a value from an included file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php). You *can* use it to implement the behaviour you want like this:

File **`if.php`**:

```
<?php 
if (Three == 3) { 
    // do something
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

File **`index.php`**:

```
<?php
if (require_once 'if.php') {
    // do something (or nothing)
} else {
   // do something else
}
```

However, I **do not recommend** this approach. The best approach is to encapsulate the test in a function:

File **`if.php`**:

```
function testSomething() {
    if (Three == 3) {
        // do something
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

File **`index.php`**:

```
require_once 'if.php';

if (testSomething()) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: Oh!!!!Thanks you guy!!! It is work!! Thank you very much!!!! You solve my problem!! Have a nice day !! Thank you so much

Comment: @axiac Why do you not recommend to use include / require in if statement?

Answer (score 1):

Its wrong way to use `if` `else` statement , blew code may help you:

**index.php**

```
<?php
    if($value == 1) { 
        include_once('first_file.php');
    }else{
        include_once('second_file.php');
    }
// ** OR **
    switch($value){
        case '1': include_once('first_file.php');break;
        case '2': include_once('second_file.php');break;
    }
 ?>
```

**first_file.php**

```
// put here the code that you want run when $value == 1
```

**second_file.php**

```
// put here the code that you want run when $value == 2
```